# Javascript Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can someone help me in this task : for each same userId I need to concatenate all title and body in the first title and body respectively.Also the key 'id' must be deleted.

example:

```
var items = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi ",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequunt rerum autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 11,
    "title": "et ea vero quia laudantium autem",
    "body": "delectus reiciendis molestiae occaecati non minima eveniet qui voluptatibus\naccusamus in eum beatae sit\nvel qu"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 12,
    "title": "in quibusdam tempore odit est dolorem",
    "body": "itaque id aut majklh"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 21,
    "title": "asperiores ea ipsam voluptatibus modi minima quia sint",
    "body": "repellat aliquid praesentium dolorem quo\nsed totam minus non      itaque\nnihil labore molestiae sunt dolor eveniet"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 22,
    "title": "dolor sint quo a velit explicabo quia nam",
    "body": "eos qui et ipsum ipsam suscipit aut\nsed omnis non odio\nexpedita earum mollitia molestiae aut atque rem suscipit\nnam impedit esse"
  }
];
```

need to become :

```
var items = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi qui                                   est esse",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequunt rerum autem sunt rem eveniet architecto est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil        reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "title": "et ea vero quia laudantium autem in quibusdam tempore odit est dolorem",
    "body": "delectus reiciendis molestiae occaecati non minima eveniet qui voluptatibus\naccusamus in eum beatae sit\nvel qu itaque id aut majklh"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "title": "asperiores ea ipsam voluptatibus modi minima quia sint dolor sint quo a velit explicabo quia nam",
    "body": "repellat aliquid praesentium dolorem quo\nsed totam minus non itaque\nnihil labore molestiae sunt dolor eveniet eos qui et ipsum ipsam       suscipit aut\nsed omnis non odio\nexpedita earum mollitia molestiae aut atque rem suscipit\nnam impedit esse"
  }];
```

Thanks for your help,
Regards
Sarah

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: You can iterate objects using `for(item in items){...}`, and you can use `delete items[item].id` to remove the `id` property.

Comment: Something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/a7em5jvq/

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi ",
      "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequunt rerum autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "qui est esse",
      "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "id": 11,
      "title": "et ea vero quia laudantium autem",
      "body": "delectus reiciendis molestiae occaecati non minima eveniet qui voluptatibus\naccusamus in eum beatae sit\nvel qu"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "id": 12,
      "title": "in quibusdam tempore odit est dolorem",
      "body": "itaque id aut majklh"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "id": 21,
      "title": "asperiores ea ipsam voluptatibus modi minima quia sint",
      "body": "repellat aliquid praesentium dolorem quo\nsed totam minus non      itaque\nnihil labore molestiae sunt dolor eveniet"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "id": 22,
      "title": "dolor sint quo a velit explicabo quia nam",
      "body": "eos qui et ipsum ipsam suscipit aut\nsed omnis non odio\nexpedita earum mollitia molestiae aut atque rem suscipit\nnam impedit esse"
    }],
  items_new = null,
  usedIds = [];


_.each(items, function (item) {
  if (!_.contains(usedIds, item.id)) {
    _.filter(items, function (subItem) {
      if (subItem.id != item.id &&
        subItem.userId == item.userId
      ) {
        item.title = item.title + ' ' + subItem.title;
        item.body = item.body + ' ' + subItem.body;
        usedIds.push(subItem.id);
      }
    });
  }
});

items_new = _.filter(items, function (item) {
  if (!_.contains(usedIds, item.id)) {
    return true;
  }
});

_.each(items_new, function (item) {
  delete item.id;
});
console.log(items_new);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3me0rjpx/